# detect if in print mode or click the print button in datatable export tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I know I can just customize my printing styles to cater my needs just by styling all the elements I desire to manipulate on printing mode by writing inside "@media print" but I'm having an issue (still figuring yet) where "@media print" dont work in my case so I decided to do something using jquery or javascript, is there a way I could detect if print mode, print window, or clicking the print button on the export tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TableTools extension adds a special class `DTTT_Print` to the `body` element, see [this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html).

You can use the following CSS rules:

```
body.DTTT_Print .sidebar { display: none !important; } 

@media print {
  .sidebar { display: none !important; } 
}
```

First rule will hide `.sidebar` in TableTools print preview mode. Second rule will ensure that `.sidebar` is hidden if the page is printed without using TableTools print preview mode.